# Как сместить "Авторизация" вниз в центр

Tags: html, css, html5

```css
.Authorization {
  font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#Authorization1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 40px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.01s ease;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#Authorization1:hover {
  background-color: rgba( 171, 203, 16, 1.0);
  border: 3px solid #1AB2B5;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_conteiner">
  <nav id="menu_nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="Main.html" class="menu"> Главная </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_2/menu_2.html" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_3/menu_3.html" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_4/menu_4.html" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="menu_5/menu_5.html" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div>
  <h1 id="name"> "Название"
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="Authorization">
  <a id="Authorization1" href="#"> Авторизация </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы хотите сместить ссылку в футер?

Comment: не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос....

Answer (score 0):

В классе .Authorization не правильно написано width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент самый простой и чистый способ прижатия контента в футер это **Flexbox**.

```css
html {
   height:100%;
}

body {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height:100%;
}

main {
   flex-grow:1;  /* задаётся что бы основная часть растягивалась на всё свободное место */
}

footer {
   background-color: olive;
   padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
   текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст
</main>
<footer>
   футер
</footer>
```

Comment: что-то не получается)

Comment: вот код для вашего примера - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEgYbq

Comment: Работает, но "Название" тоже смещается в нижнюю часть экрана

Comment: Что я делаю не так?)

Comment: Не знаю, в моём примере название под меню наверху а "авторизация" внизу.

Comment: Вы же в примере никакие стили для названия и 'menu_conteiner' не задали, вот оно и смещается под меню... я взял код из вашего примера. Если вы хотите какие-то стили для названия или 'menu_conteiner', то вам и надо их в явную прописать. Я же не могу догадаться какие у вас там должны быть стили.

Comment: Все, полный html и css код страницы сюда вставил

Comment: @DoZa Play А что в вопрос вставлять то? Вы просто вставьте код который я дал к себе в проект, разумеется надо не тупо весь код вставить, а думаючи совместить. Вам в любом случае с этим придётся самому разбираться, так как такие задачи если вы программируете сайт будут появляться постоянно. Я конечно могу вам вставить этот код, но какой в этом смысл, если вы с этим сами не разберётесь, и в следующей задачи опять будете вопрос писать на StackOverflow.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а уже так и происходит. Каждый день новый вопрос. Доза, я вам советую сначала полностью представить, как будет выглядеть сайт, попытаться сделать, а потом вопросы задавать, если что-то не получается. Люди стараются, помогают непонятно зачем... Вчера вот по центру нужно было "Название" разместить. Я могу сказать - располагать что-то внизу экрана нужно в крайне редких случаях - когда контента на странице меньше высоты экрана. У вас точно будет такая пустая страница? Если нет - не нужно заморачиваться с этим футером.